# Best way to read and write to csv files: pandas functions vs csv library?

Tags: python, csv

I'm doing some exercises on Udacity.

With the pandas library dealing with csv files seems super intuitive. After importing pandas as pd I can just do:

**Read file**

```
pd.read_csv("file_path")
```

**Write file**

```
pd.to_csv("file name")
```

In comparison if I import the csv library the code seems unintuitive. I have to do this:

**Read file**

```
with open("file_path", 'rb') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
```

**Write file**

```
with open("file name", 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
```

Why should I choose the csv library if if pandas read/write is so straighforward?

Answer (score 1):

You should use whatever works best for you! Csv is native, so it's pretty easy to move your code to other platforms or machines. That might be an advantage in some circumstances. But if you're comfortable with panda, you should definitely use it!

Answer (score 0):

The two program that you have are doing very different thing. `pd.read_csv()` slurps the entire file into memory, while `csv.reader(f)` reads only as needed. A more equivalent comparison is `pd.read_csv(chunksize=chunksize)`.

The problem with the pandas version is that it is not guaranteed to clean up the file handles as soon as you no longer need it. Python guarantees that it will close a file handle when the file handle is garbage collected, but it does not guarantee **when** garbage collection happens. If you open thousands of files, you may find yourself unexpectedly running out of file handles even when you never have more than a few handles at a time.

In CPython, which uses reference counting which means that garbage collection is immediate, this may not be much of an issue because CPython will actually close the file handle as soon as there are no more reference to the file object. But most other Python implementations uses garbage collection strategies that may delay garbage collection until the sweeping thread comes along. If you're confident that your application only will run in CPython and if you're only writing short lived program that doesn't open too many files, then you can just do `reader = csv.reader(open(filename))`.

But under the circumstances where the issues described above might occur, the pandas version is not safe either when you use chunked reading (which is needed for processing really large files). You should be using a context manager as well to be safe in that case:

```
for filename in lots_of_files:
    with open(filename) as f:
        for chunk in pd.read_csv(f, chunksize=chunksize):
            process(chunk)
```

All in all, the use of with-statement for closing file handle is mostly pedanticism until you need to work under the circumstances where it might be a problem. It's a good practice to always close your file handles, but if you know that your program won't be opening more than a few files or if you know you only need to run on CPython, you usually don't need to worry too much about it if it doesn't cause you an issue.